# Testing - acheving condition coverage with nested if's?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, code-coverage

I am trying to find out if it's possible to have a set of test inputs that achieves 100% condition coverage for the following code.

```
bool a = ...;
bool b = ...;
if (a == True){
    if (b == True && a == False){
        ...
    } else{
        ...
    }
} else{
    ...
}
```

However, most of the resources I have found only deal with one condition. Therefore I am not sure what to do with nested ifs. Specifically, I am not sure what to do with the second if statement. Since "a == False" should never be true given the outer if statement, is it correct to say that this code can never have 100% condition coverage test cases?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible: `(b == True && a == False)` will never be true, since it's inside a block

```
if (a == True)
```

a can't be true and false at the same time. Either there is a bug, or you have dead code that should simply be removed. And then, you can have 100% coverage.

Comment: Technically, shouldn't 100% condition coverage only require test inputs that have a and b be true and false at some point? Or each if in the algorithm has to be treated separately?